# Amazon Linux 2023: systcl kernel parameters - network - hardening and tuning review

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux-networking, amazon-linux, sysctl

We are in the process of transitioning to Amazon Gnu/Linux 2023, and during the course of this migration, I came across some Ansible code that modifies kernel parameters.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could review the parameters below and provide me with your feedback and comments.

Server Type: Web servers (w/ NGINX) - EC2 Instances t3a.medium

Stacks: PHP & Golang

```
# Tune Kernel
sysctl_params: [
  # Network Hardening
  { name: 'net.ipv4.ip_forward', value: 0 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6', value: 1 },
  # Network Tunning
  { name: 'net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range', value: '1024 65535' },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control', value: 'cubic' },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog', value: 65535 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem', value: '4096 87380 16777216' },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_wmem', value: '4096 65536 16777216' },
  { name: 'net.core.somaxconn', value: 65535 },
  { name: 'net.core.rmem_max', value: 16777216 },
  { name: 'net.core.wmem_max', value: 16777216 },
  { name: 'net.core.netdev_max_backlog', value: 16384 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack', value: 1 },
  { name: 'net.ipv4.tcp_fack', value: 1 }
]
```